# How to use tinybox in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>JSP Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="tinybox.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <label>Name :</label><input type="text" id="name" onclick="tiny();"/>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function tiny(show)
        {
            TINY.box().show(ajax.html,show,300,150,true,500) ;  
        }
      </script>
</body>
```

The above code is not working in jsp.please help me how to use tinybox in jsp.ajax.html page is already present in same location of this page.

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: @reporter2 when i click the textfield the ajax.html is not pop up.or please correct the code.

Comment: yes its just a html page

Answer (score 0):

There may be two reasons for this

**1.** You need to use **request.getContextPath()** to get the context path, as you are using **JSP** and need to append that to ajax.html

Here is a snippet how it will look,

TINY.box().show('**<%= request.getContextPath() %>**/ajax.html','show',300,150,true,500) ;

**2.** You are **missing quotes in "ajax.html"**. Javascript will throw error when try to use ajax.html without quotes around it.

Comment: That's right, though I followed the instructions from websites and couldn't run the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I've got something.

It exists two versions of this framework.

Here the code for ****Tinybox 1****:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox/tinybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function tiny(show)
{
 TINY.box.show("ajax.html",show,300,150,true,5);  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <label>Name: </label><input type="text" id="name" onclick="tiny(true)"/>
</body>
<html>
```

If the value of variable `show` was true (or 1), it seems the tinybox want to include the given file, via iframe. Wether my IE9, FF21 and Chrome browser could open the file (the browsers complained an access validation). At the opposit, a valid external URL did work.

Here the code for ****Tinybox 2****:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/tinybox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function tiny(show)
    {
      TINY.box.show({iframe:'ajax.html',width:300,height:150})
     }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <label>Name: </label><input type="text" id="name" onclick="tiny(true)"/>
</body>
<html>
```

This version did work perfectly.